# A non-cyclic proper subgroup of $(\Bbb{Q},+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, infinite-groups

I need to show that $H$ is a proper non-cyclic subgroup of $(\Bbb{Q}, +)$ where

$$H = \left\{\frac{m}{2^n}: m \in \Bbb{Z}, n\in\Bbb{N}\right\} $$

First if I need to show it is a subgroup, I need to show that it is non-empty subset of $\Bbb{Q}$ and $a + b^{-1} \in H$ for all $a, b \in H$.

This is clear that $H$ is a non-empty subset of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Now let $\frac{m_1}{2^{n_1}}$ and $\frac{m_2}{2^{n_2}}$ be in $H$.

Then it is clear that $\frac{m_1}{2^{n_1}} - \frac{m_2}{2^{n_2}}$ will be in $H$.

It is clear that $H$ will be proper.

Next, how can I show that it is non-cyclic?

Comment: Have you tried bringing the two fractions on the same denominator?

Comment: “$a+b^{-1}$” is either an error, or horribly misuse of notation. This is an additive group, so what you need to check is that $a-b$ lies in $H$ whenever $a$ and $b$ are in $H$. Not that $a+b^{-1}$ (which in this situation actually makes sense because $H$ sits inside a ring) does.

Comment: HINT: Show that $\langle \frac{m}{k}\rangle$ cannot contain any fraction which, when written in lowest terms, has a denominator greater than $k$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin..isn't b$^{-1}$ -b only?..that is what I meant...I think a+b$^{-1}$ reduces to a-b in this case?

Comment: @Gitika: It’s bad notation to mix additive and multiplicative notation, *especially* in a setting where the two operations already exist and have meaning. So, no, “$a+b^{-1}$” does’t “reduce” to $a-b$. The two expressions mean different things in the rationals, so don’t use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be cyclic is to be generated by one element.

A typical non-identity element is a number of the form $\dfrac m {2^n}$  for some $m\in\mathbb Z, n \in \{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}.$

The subgroup generated by $\dfrac m {2^n}$ is $\left\{ \dfrac{mk}{2^n} : k\in \mathbb Z \right\}.$ The number $\dfrac 1 {2^{n+1}}$ is a member of $H$ but not of the group generated by $\dfrac m {2^n}.$

Answer (score 4):

You have to show that $a-b\in H$, not $a+b^{-1}$, because you're considering $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to addition.

Saying “it is clear” is not really a proof.

Consider instead
$$
\frac{x}{2^m}-\frac{y}{2^n}=\frac{2^nx-2^my}{2^{m+n}}
$$
which actually shows that the difference belongs to $H$.

Why is $H$ proper? Because there are no integers $m$ and $n\ge0$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{3}=\frac{m}{2^n}
$$
because $3$ does not divide $2^n$.

Finally, take $m/2^n\in H$ and find something in $H$ that's not an integral multiple of this element. Hint: use a larger denominator.